# How do I add an email cc into my Google Script

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

I have a Google Script that I've inherited and I'm looking to update it to reflect current requirements.

Currently it fires off 2 emails to a participant and sponsor using data in a Google Sheet. I've tried combining it so that section 'Now email for each doc' sends an email to the participant and cc's the sponsor.

**I've gotten as far as updating the code from :**

```
var sendTo = row[EMAIL];
```

**to :**

```
var sendTo = row[EMAIL] + " , " + sponsors;
```

and removing section '2. Personal Case' which doesn't solve the cc query.

I've tried amending the existing code to add in the additional parameters as stated on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app but can't seem to get it to work in the code below.

```
// Now email for each doc
  var email = getAppraiseeEmail();
  if(email && email.body) {
    email.body = email.body.replaceAll('%doctitle1%', bTitle)
     /*.replaceAll('%doctitle2%', pTitle)
     .replaceAll('%doctitle3%', dTitle)
     .replaceAll('%doctitle4%', dpTitle)
     .replaceAll('%link1%', bFile.getUrl())
     .replaceAll('%link2%', pFile.getUrl())
     .replaceAll('%link3%', dFile.getUrl())
     .replaceAll('%link4%', dpFile.getUrl())*/
     .replaceAll('%link5%', child.getUrl())
     .replaceAll('%name%', row[NAME]);

    var sendTo = row[EMAIL];
    if(sendTo && sendTo!=='') {
      email.recipient = sendTo;
      sendAnEmail(email);
    }
  } else {
    throw Error('missing email configuration (Business Case)');
  }


// 2. Personal Case
  if(sponsors.length > 0) {
    var emailRev = getSponsorEmail();
    if(emailRev && emailRev.body) {
      emailRev.body = emailRev.body.replaceAll('%doctitle1%', bTitle)
      /*.replaceAll('%doctitle2%', pTitle)
      .replaceAll('%doctitle3%', dTitle)
      .replaceAll('%doctitle4%', dpTitle)
      .replaceAll('%link1%', bFile.getUrl())
      .replaceAll('%link2%', pFile.getUrl())
      .replaceAll('%link3%', dFile.getUrl())
      .replaceAll('%link4%', dpFile.getUrl()) */
      .replaceAll('%link5%', child.getUrl())
      .replaceAll('%name%', row[NAME]);

      var sendTo = sponsors.join(',');
      if(sendTo && sendTo!=='') {
        emailRev.recipient = sendTo;
        sendAnEmail(emailRev);
      }
    } else {
      throw Error('missing email configuration (sponsor)');
    }
  } // end if re sponsors

  row[NOTES] = 'Files created & shared, ' + timestamp;
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
  row[NOTES] = 'An error occurred (' + e + '), ' + timestamp;
}

function getAppraiseeEmail() {
var email = {};
email.body = getConfig('email01');
email.subject = getConfig('subject01');
return email;
}

function getSponsorEmail() {
var email = {};
email.body = getConfig('email02');
email.subject = getConfig('subject02');
return email;
}

function sendAnEmail(email) {
var options = { noReply: true, htmlBody: email.body };
MailApp.sendEmail(email.recipient, email.subject, null , options);
}
```

Ideally it should fire out the email from section 'Now email for each doc' and cc the sponsors in section '2. Personal Case'.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE 15/07/19

I've updated the code to the below which now works:

```
// Now email for each doc
   var email = getAppraiseeEmail();
  if(email && email.body) {
    email.body = email.body.replaceAll('%doctitle1%', bTitle)
                           .replaceAll('%link5%', child.getUrl())
                           .replaceAll('%name%', row[NAME]);

    var CC = row[SPONSORS]
    var sendTo = row[EMAIL]
    if(sendTo && sendTo!=='') {
      email.recipientTO = sendTo;
      email.CC = CC;
      sendAnEmail(email); 
    }
  } else {
    throw Error('missing email configuration (Business Case)');
  }

 row[NOTES] = 'Files created & shared, ' + timestamp;
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
  row[NOTES] = 'An error occurred (' + e + '), ' + timestamp;
}

function getAppraiseeEmail() {
var email = {};
email.body = getConfig('email01');
email.subject = getConfig('subject01');
return email;
}

function sendAnEmail(email) {
var options = { noReply: true, htmlBody: email.body, cc: email.CC };
MailApp.sendEmail(email.recipientTO, email.subject, null , options);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the cc address in your `var options` ?

Comment: As @ross pointed out, try to add "cc" in your MailApp options, as you can see in the [MailApp documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

Comment: Thanks @ross and Jescanellas. I've updated var options to                  function sendAnEmail(email) {
  var options = { noReply: true, htmlBody: email.body, cc: email.sponsors};
  MailApp.sendEmail(email.recipientTO, email.subject, null , options);
}      and added it to the section below    var sendTo = row[EMAIL]
        var sendCc = sponsors[i]
        if(sendTo && sendTo!=='') {
          email.recipientTO = sendTo;
          email.sponsors = sendCc;
          sendAnEmail(email);                       The script runs with no issues but doesn't cc :-(

Comment: @codinghelp Add this to the question not a comment, no one wants to read through and try to figure out your code from the comment.

Comment: Do a test and see if cc = 'email@mail.com' works correctly. Also, add the code you commented to your post so we will have a better idea of what you tried.